# Linking same variable between csv and json in d3

Tags: javascript, json, csv, d3.js, svg

I'm currently want to make a world map using d3.

I'm using `https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/50m.json` to load the data to draw out the world map where one of the variable, `id` is same with my `dataset2010.csv`, `Country_code`.

how can I link this 2 files through json's `id` and csv's `Country_code`.

Following is my `main.js`

```
(function (d3,topojson) {
  'use strict';

  const svg = d3.select('svg');

  const projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1();
  const pathGenerator = d3.geoPath().projection(projection);

  const g = svg.append('g');

  g.append('path')
      .attr('class', 'sphere')
      .attr('d', pathGenerator({type: 'Sphere'}));

  svg.call(d3.zoom().on('zoom', () => {
    g.attr('transform', d3.event.transform);
  }));

  Promise.all([
    d3.json('https://unpkg.com/world-atlas@1.1.4/world/50m.json'),
    d3.csv('dataset2010.csv')
  ]).then(([topoJSONdata, csvData]) => {


    // here I could not link them
    const countryName = {};
    csvData.forEach(d => {
      countryName[d.Country_code] = d.name;
      console.log(d.Country_code);
      console.log(d.name);
    });



    const countries = topojson.feature(topoJSONdata, topoJSONdata.objects.countries);
    g.selectAll('path').data(countries.features)
      .enter().append('path')
        .attr('class', 'country')
        .attr('d', pathGenerator)
      .append('title')
        .text(d => countryName[d.id]); //the d.id is from the json file.

  });

}(d3,topojson));
```

Comment: What do you mean by linking? Something like merging both objects?

Comment: @BrunoFenzl : Is like a database, `PK` and `FK`. All the data that I wanted to display is inside the `dataset2010.csv` file and the `50m.json` file is for the world map design. One of the attributes between these 2 files is the same. which is `id` from `50m.json` and `Country_code` from `dataset2010.csv`.